# .done() not getting called on reconnect in signalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

On my MVC4 ASP.NET web page, I have the code below within the javascript for dealing with the connection to the server and re-connection to the server (if connection is lost with the server for some reason).

The trouble is `$.connection.hub.start().done()` is not getting called in response to `$.connection.hub.start()` for the reconnect (its only getting called when it is issued the first time). Is this a bug I wonder? If not, is there an equivalent way to alert the client that `start()` has completed.

```
// Start the signalR connection and request the default page
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.info("$.connection.hub.start().done");
    hubProxy.server.sendDefaultPage();
});


//if server goes away - reconnect to it
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    console.info("disconnected");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.connection.hub.start();
    }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your connection start logic into a function:

```
function startConnection() {
    // Start the signalR connection and request the default page
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        console.info("$.connection.hub.start().done");
        hubProxy.server.sendDefaultPage();
    });
}

//if server goes away - reconnect to it
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    console.info("disconnected");
    setTimeout(startConnection, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

Then the .done() callback will be called on both the initial connect and your reconnect.